# Variable concatenate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery code where i do this :

```
            var resuSave = "";
            $(".attachFile").each(function()
            {
               $.ajax({
                  url: monurl.php
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: myData,
                  type: 'POST',
                  success: function(data)
                  {
                     resuSave = resuSave.concat(data);
                  }
               });
            });
            alert(resuSave);
```

But my variable `resuSave` still alert an empty string. So i try to initialize `resuSave` at `"toto"` and do an alert of it in the success of my ajax request and their is "toto" in my alert. I also do an `alert(data)` and it's print me some text. So i don't understand why this code don't want to put some text in my variable resuSave.

Comment: Have you try resuSave  +=  data and in ajax call  type: 'POST' is defined two times

Comment: Thank you you right i didn't see for the type. But yea i try and it don't work too

Comment: But it's work if i do like it's explain here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call